# What kind of bug is this one?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

We are trying to figure out what kind of bug this is? It appears to have larvae on its back it is not dust and debris.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is some sort of Neuroptera

Comment: Karl's answer is about as far as we can go without size and locality information, and by the way, that _is_ debris on the animal's back ...

Comment: It looks like an earwig to me, they're great parents too, lugging all their young around with them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of neuroptera larva https://www.google.com/search?q=neuroptera+larva.

The smooth jaws discard an antlion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antlion.

Is more like a chyrsopidae https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=neuroptera+larva&chips=q:neuroptera+larvae,g_1:chrysopidae:qWI0Ngq4zAQ%3D. They like to camouflage with debris found around them.

Comment: i cant really tell but, the op's photo doesn't look like it has hair on its leg, antlion definitely has hair on its legs. But you know cant really tell